# Pass target to jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I want to create a function that lays out a button - in doing so I would like to pass a custom target - is this possible?

```
function appendHeroButton(parent, child, text, target, x, y, w, h){

    var childDiv = $("<div id='"+child+"' class='heroButton noselect' style='left:"+x+"px; top:"+y+"px; width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px; position:absolute; background-color:"+action+"; line-height:"+h+"px;'>"+text+"</div>");
    $("#"+parent).append(childDiv);

    var div = document.getElementById(child);   
    div.addEventListener('click', target);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom target?

Comment: Do you want to pass a function as the target parameter and then do something with the div that has the event listener in that function?

Comment: The use of `target` in this example is an event callback, which is oddly named.

Comment: The target is the function that should be executed when the user clicks the div. Perhaps selector would be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, you want a callback to be added as a param to your `appendHeroButton` function, and attached to the `div`.

Here is an example of doing so, you can simply just reference the function by name, then you can interact with the `div` if needed using the passed `event`.

```js
function appendHeroButton(parent, child, text, target, x, y, w, h){

    var childDiv = $("<div id='"+child+"' class='heroButton noselect' style='left:"+x+"px; top:"+y+"px; width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px; position:absolute; background-color:red; line-height:"+h+"px;'>"+text+"</div>");
    $("#"+parent).append(childDiv);

    var div = document.getElementById(child);   
    div.addEventListener('click', target);

}

var someFunction = function (e) {
  var div = $(e.currentTarget);
  console.log(div.text());
};

var parent = "foo";
var child = "bar";
var targetFn = someFunction;

appendHeroButton(parent, child, "text", targetFn, 10, 50, 100, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">Click here</div>
</div>
```